# jquery animate function callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I have a jquery animate function with a callback that isn't firing, I think it's something simple that another pair of eyes will pick up quickly.  This is the code:

```
$('#base_back_img').animate({
  width:372,
  height:389,
  marginLeft:0,
  paddingTop:0,
  marginTop:1
}, {duration:300, queue:false},
  function() {
   $('#menu-text').css({
     display:'block'
   });     
   $('#mini-menu').fadeOut();
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using animate with an object as argument, you need to use `complete` just like that :

```
$('#base_back_img').animate({
    width:372,
    height:389,
    marginLeft:0,
    paddingTop:0,
    marginTop:1
}, {duration:300,
    queue:false,
    complete : function() {
        $('#menu-text').css({
            display:'block'
        });     
        $('#mini-menu').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

See all properties here : http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move your callback into your options object, like this:

```
$('#base_back_img').animate({
  width:372,
  height:389,
  marginLeft:0,
  paddingTop:0,
  marginTop:1
}, 
{duration:300,
 queue:false,
 complete:function() {
   $('#menu-text').css({
      display:'block'
   });     
 $('#mini-menu').fadeOut();
}
```

}
  );